# Errors with java applet

Tags: java, button, applet, actionlistener

I am trying to write an applet that will calculate the average amount of four input boxes or clear all fields depending on which box is clicked. I think I have it mostly right, but there is an error somewhere causing the following error statement to appear:
     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 10" Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class blooddriveaverage extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
 public void init() 
 {
   Label title = new Label("Blood Drive!");
  setBackground(Color.red);
  Label label1 = new Label("Department 1 amount: ");

  textField1 = new TextField(" ");

  avg = new Button("Average");
  clear = new Button ("Clear Fields");
  avg.addActionListener(this);
  clear.addActionListener(this);

  Label label2 = new Label("Department 2 amount: ");
  textField2 = new TextField(" ");
  Label label3 = new Label("Department 3 amount: ");
  textField3 = new TextField(" ");
  Label label4 = new Label("Department 4 amount: ");
  textField4 = new TextField(" ");

  add(title);
  add(label1);
  add(textField1);
  add(label2);
  add(textField2);
  add(label3);
  add(textField3);
  add(label4);
  add(textField4);
  add(avg);
  add(clear);
  avg.setBackground(Color.white);
  clear.setBackground(Color.orange);

 }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
   setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
   double average = 0;
   int[] myarray = new int[3];
   myarray[0] = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
   myarray[1] = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
   myarray[2] = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
   myarray[3] = Integer.parseInt(textField4.getText());

   if (e.getSource() == avg)
   {
  for(int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
   {
    average += myarray[i];
   }
  average /=4;
  Label avgfield = new Label("Average is" + average);

  }

   else
   {
    textField1.setText(" ");
    textField2.setText(" ");
    textField3.setText(" ");  
    textField4.setText(" ");
   }
 }

 TextField textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4;
 Button avg;
 Button clear;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the exception. It is thrown at this line:

```
myarray[0] = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
```

The problem is that it can't parse the String as a number because it has spaces (e.g. `10`). What you need to do is removed the leading and trailing whitespace with trim():

```
myarray[0] = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText().trim());
```

That should fix the NumberFormatException, but other errors remain.

Comment: Ok, I have done both of these, and I am no longer getting errors, however the average is not being printed. It says avgfield is never read. I thought I would have to put that line up with the rest of the labels, but it says the variable average wasn't initialized. If I try to return average from the actionperformed method it says that method cannot return a value. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2933941: where do you add the avgField to the GUI? Declare it in the class, and add it to the GUI in the init method.

Comment: You are actually calculating the average and creating the label. But you never use the label: Label avgfield = new Label("Average is" + average);

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the variable average from the actionPerformed method to the init method? I cant use a return statement in the actionPeformed method.

Comment: One thing you can do is add a private member to your class: JLabel avgfield. Add it to your applet. Then right after you calculate the average, set the label to it:  avgfield.setText(average);

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong. You're trying to parse `" 10"`, and that extra space has significance.

- Suggestion one: call `trim()` on your Strings before parsing to get rid of leading and trailing white space.
- Suggestion two, don't create your textfields or clear your text fields by putting in a space but rather an empty String.

e.g., change:

```
textField2 = new TextField(" ");
```

and

```
else
{
  textField1.setText(" ");
  textField2.setText(" ");
  textField3.setText(" ");  
  textField4.setText(" ");
}
```

to:

```
textField2 = new TextField("");

else
{
  textField1.setText("");
  textField2.setText("");
  textField3.setText("");  
  textField4.setText("");
}
```

This will decrease the risk of a space being in the the number String.

- Suggestion 3: use the Swing GUI library, not the AWT library.
- Suggestion 4: In the future, consider creating a more informative question subject heading. `"Errors with java applet"` tells us little about your actual problem and might not attract the experts for that specific problem. A better question title might be, `"NumberFormatException problem when parsing applet TextField text"`, or something similar.